# CString error, 'CString': is not a member of 'ATL::CStringT<BaseType, StringTraits>'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, cstring

I am trying to do this:

```
#include <atlstr.h>

CHAR Filename; // [sp+26Ch] [bp-110h]@1
char v31; // [sp+36Ch] [bp-10h]@1
int v32; // [sp+378h] [bp-4h]@1

 GetModuleFileNameA(0, &Filename, 0x100u);
 CString::CString(&v31, &Filename);
```

But I am getting the compiler error C2039:'CString': is not a member of 'ATL::CStringT'

This is a non MFC based dll, but according to the docs you should be able to use CString functionality with the include #include atlstr.h how do I make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how constructors are invoked in C++.

`CString s = CString(&v21,&File);`

Note that `GetModuleFilename` expects a pointer to an array of characters (which it fills), not a pointer to a single character. Your code is therefore doomed to crash at runtime.

Comment: Alex, I understand that GetModuleFilename does require a char array, buy my question was more: why does the CString call generate that error?

Comment: Because you didn't call the constructor correctly. Constructors in C++ are no regular members of their classes and they're not static either - calling `foo::bar` implies that `bar` must be a static member of `foo`. See my response for a possible way to go.

Comment: Sorry Alex, little stressed and I missed the point of what you said.  I get it now and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in this code snippet:

1) `CHAR Filename;` declares a variable that is only a single character. However, `GetModuleFileNameA` expects to be given a pointer to an array of characters. When you pass the parameters `&Filename` and `0x100u` you would make it think that `&Filename` points to an array of memory with room for up to 256 characters. However, as written in your snipped, it's only a single character. Thus you would have a bad buffer overflow.

`Filename` should most likely be declared as `CHAR Filename[0x100];` in this case. That would also mean you don't need to take the address of Filename when passing it to that function. So the call would then be written as `GetModuleFileNameA(0, Filename, 0x100u);`

2) When writing code for a constructor, you define is by writing something similar to `CString::CString` (using whatever your class's name is) and then filling out the function. However, when using a constructor you don't use that syntax at all. You don't call `CString::CString()` to create a `CString` object.

You would have to choose an name for the `CString` object, such as "FilenameStr". So the in the context of you code you would write something like `CString FilenameStr(Filename);`

3) As implied at the end of the last point, the parameters you are trying to pass to the constructor are wrong. `&v31` and `&Filename` would each by pointers to characters in your original code. However, as far as I know, CString does not have any constructor that takes two character pointers.

I can't even tell how `v31` is supposed to be involved there, but it doesn't seem necessary at all. If you want to fill a CString with the contents of a character array, then you can just pass that array to the constructor and it will take care of everything. So, something like `CString FilenameStr(Filename);`